# Reordering items QAbstractListModel -- dropMimeData never called

Tags: qt, pyside

I have class `MyListModel`, which inherits from QAbstractListModel that is being displayed using a QListView or custom subclass. I would like each item in the list to be editable, and for the user to be able to drag and drop to rearrange the order of the items (I'm not actually convinced a QListView is the way to go, but it looked like it would work without too much trouble. Oh well.).

The items are draggable, but display the little crossed out circle, meaning I can't drop anything there.

I tried everything suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355510/qt-what-needs-to-be-done-for-a-custom-model-to-enable-drop), and nothing seems to work. The `dropMimeData` function is never called, although the `mimeData` seems to produce my placeholder data.

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong in the other classes, so I'm just putting the model class in this post. The spacing may be a bit funky.

Thank you for any help.

My Model:

```
class MyListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

def __init__(self, parent, items=None):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
    print "initiating MyListModel"
    self.parent = parent
    self._items = list()

    for thing in items:
        self._items.append(thing)

    self.setSupportedDragActions(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)

def rowCount(self, parent = QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    return len(self._items)

def data(self, index, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if (role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole) or (role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        return self._items[index.row()].name
    else:
        return 

def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
    print "Setting Data", value, "at", index.row(), 

    if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        print "EditRole"
        self._items[index.row()].name = value
        return True
    elif role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        print "DisplayRole"
        print role
        return False
    else:
        print "other"
        print role
        return False


def flags(self, index):
    return (QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled |
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | 
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | 
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | 
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)

def insertRows(self, row, count, parent):
    print "insertRows"
    self.beginInsertRows(parent, row, (row + (count - 1)))
    #self._items.insert(row, object)
    self.endInsertRows() 
    return True 


def supportedDropActions(self):
    print "supportedDrop"
    return (QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)

def supportedDragActions(self):
    print "supportedDraw"
    return (QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)

def mimeData(self, indexes):
    print "mimeData at (", indexes[0].row(), ",", indexes[0].column(), ")",
    self.old_index = indexes[0].row()

    old_stuff = pickle.dumps(self._items[indexes[0].row()])
    print type(old_stuff)
    mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
    mimeData.setText(old_stuff)

    return mimeData

def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent):
    print "dropMimeData"
    '''
    self.beginInsertRows(parentIndex, row, row)

    if action == QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction: 
        return True 

    if data.hasText():
        print data
    return False
    '''

def mimeTypes(self):
    print 'mimeTypes'
    return list("text/plain")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `mimeData` method, try changing `mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()` to `mimeData = super(MyListModel, self).mimeData(indexes)`.

I believe that there's a problem with the lifetime of the `mimeData` object if you create it yourself, where it gets deleted too soon. If you do the above, it seems to have the correct lifetime. This is just a guess, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but you should also set the drap & drop mode in your view.

```
class MyListView(QListView):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QListView.__init__(self, parent)

    self._model = MyListModel(self)
    self.setModel(self._model)

    self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
```

[Documentation](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDropMode)